# C Programming - Using Parallel Arrays to enter Names, Exercise Marks and Compute Average of Exercise Marks and Display

Tags: arrays, c, global-variables

I'm doing self-study on C Programming, and I have been recommended the following C Program by my colleagues to study further, where you can enter the Name and Age and it displays and uses Insert, Delete, Display, and Exit menu options.

I'm trying to convert it to my current study stream logic scenario where I need to enter the Name, Exercise Mark 1 (up to 3), and then it computes the Average and gets displayed while employing the Insert, Delete, Display, Update (updating the scores only, not the names), Delete and Exit.

Any guidance please on how to learn this code and understand the logic, and apply it to the 2nd scenario will be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50
//using parallel arrays as fields in the list
typedef struct list{
    char name[MAX][31];
    int age[MAX];
    int last;
}LIST;
LIST L;//L structure is global

void save();
void retrieve();
void makenull();
void insert(char n[31],int a);
void del(char n[31]);
void display();
int locate(char n[31]);
int isfull();
int isempty();
int menu();

int main(){
char nm[31];
int ag;
makenull();
retrieve();
while(1){
    switch(menu()){
    case 1: system("cls");printf("Insert Mode\n");
            printf("Input Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);
            printf("Input Age: ");scanf("%d",&ag);insert(nm,ag);break;
    case 2: system("cls");printf("Delete Mode\n");
            printf("Input Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);del(nm);break;
    case 3: display();break;
    case 4: save();exit(0);
    default: printf("\n1-4 lang!\n");system("pause");
    }
}
return 0;
}
void makenull(){
   L.last = -1;
}
void insert(char n[31],int a){
if (isfull()){
    printf("List is full.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else {
    L.last++;
    strcpy(L.name[L.last],n);
    L.age[L.last]=a;
}

}
void del(char n[31]){
int p;
if (isempty()){
    printf("List is empty.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else {
    p=locate(n);
    if (p==-1){
        printf("Not found.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = p;i<L.last;i++){
            strcpy(L.name[i],L.name[i+1]);
            L.age[i]=L.age[i+1];
        }
        L.last--;
        printf("Successful delete operation.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
  }
}
void display(){
int i;
system("cls");
printf("  Name     Age \n");
for(i=0;i<=L.last;i++)
    printf("%d.) %s     %d\n",i+1,L.name[i],L.age[i]);
system("pause");
}
int locate(char n[31]){
int i;
for (i=0;i<=L.last;i++)
    if(strcmp(L.name[i],n)==0)
         return i;
return -1;
}
int isfull(){
  if (L.last==MAX-1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
int isempty(){
  return(L.last==-1);
}
int menu(){
int op;
system("cls");
printf("MENU\n");
printf("1. Insert\n");
printf("2. Delete\n");
printf("3. Display\n");
printf("4. Exit\n");
printf("\nSelect(1-4): ");
scanf("%d",&op);
return(op);
}
void save(){
FILE *fp;
int i;
fp=fopen("Practice4.dbf","w+");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("File Error.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else{
    for (i=0;i<=L.last;i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%s %d\n",L.name[i],L.age[i]);
}
fclose(fp);
}
void retrieve(){
FILE *fp;
char n[31];
int i,a;
fp=fopen("Practice4.dbf","r+");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("File Error.\n");
    system("pause");
}
else {
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d\n",n,&a);
        insert(n,a);
    }

}
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: and in programming (in `C`) on which level you are? viz. beginner, intermediate, etc.
It would be much better if you try to write your own separate program for what you are describing here and then put that into this program.

Comment: Beginner, just learned Global and Local Functions, and now reading up on Arrays from TutorialsPoint and YouTube videos.

Comment: Then I would say, take a step back and learn all other things before digging into this code. Cause it's using _pointers, file-handling, etc_ and I guess you are unaware of these concepts. BTW, you should try what I said earlier, it's not that tough.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham.  Do you have any C Programming references that you can recommend when you started out?

I am referring earlier to these references when self-studying, and there might be better resources that you know of:
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_quick_guide.htm
- Caleb Curry YouTube Channel (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZUyPT9DkJWmS_DzdOi7RIA)

Comment: I'd rather recommend [The C programming language](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=the+c+programming+language&qid=1622865883&sr=8-1) by K&R.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, reading it now and practicing The For statement, apprecaite your help @Shubham

Comment: Thanks @Shubham.  If you have time, I posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851166/xwidgets-debug-alert-message-on-codeblocks-any-help-is-appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't properly formatted and there are no comments. I can't give you a direct answer with some code in it, but summing up all my comments (and of course I deleted them), this is what I've to say:

Consider this scenario-

> if your `.dbf` has more than `MAX 50` elements, then your `while (!feof(fp))` inside `retrieve()` will keep calling `insert()` and `insert()` will keep executing its `if () { }` block.

You should put something like `while (!feof(fp) && L.last < MAX)` to prevent that situation and you'll need to further modify your code in `insert()`. Another thing is, this code doesn't have any `update()` function and `scores` variable. You'll need to add `scores` in your `struct` as well as there must be `scores` fields in your `.dbf`.

Now, for a moment let's say everything else is good to go in your code, then you should follow these following steps:

- Declare variables

```
char nameInput[31];
float ex_marks[3], sum = 0, avr = 0;
```

in `main()`.

- Add another `case 5` in your `switch ()` block inside `main()` and translate and convert the following **pseudocode** into `C` code:

1. Read `name` in `nameInput`
2. `locate()`
3. if found then
   3.a for `i = 0` to `2`
   Read `marks` in `ex_marks[i]`
   `sum = sum + ex_marks[i]`
   3.b Calculate `avr = sum / 3`
   3.c Display `name` and `avr`
4. else
   Display `name` is not in the list.
5. exit

Also read about [`why is while(!feof()) always wrong?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)